# Number of threads in relation to num.standby.replicas

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Asking to confirm if my reasoning is correct.

My application has 12 input partitions spread across 3 instances of applications.
Normally, I would expect number of threads to be set as 4 given that 4 partitions equals 4 tasks what indicates at most 4 threads.
However, my application maintains state in statestore with `num.standby.replicas` configured to 2. Given that this setting should result in processing changelog across 12 partitions, would it make sense to change threads to 12?

During restarts/rebalances I get `WARN` as below:

`Unable to assign 1 of 2 standby tasks for task [0_0] There is not enough available capacity. You should increase the number of threads and/or application instances to maintain the requested number of standby replicas.`

Is this an indication of sub-optimal configuration which may result in bad performance? (when rebalancing or context switching between tasks to catch up with changelog)

Answer (score 0):

num.standby.replicas refers to standby tasks.

https://medium.com/wise-engineering/rack-awareness-in-kafka-streams-448d7e5225a3 explains it all better.